# Is it possible to get squashed commits' history back

Tags: git, squash

Git rookie here. I squashed several commits into one commit and push the single commit to a remote repository already. Now I want to get some of squashed commits back. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you do an interactive rebase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `git reflog`. If you are on the same machine you'll see something like

[image: image taken from gitready.com]

You can get back your commits back using `git cherry-pick` or see them using `git show`.

For more details visit: [this link](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html)

Comment: Screen shot credit http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `git reflog` to either reset or cherry-pick previous commits. Check out this article that goes into detail on what it is and how to use it. http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html